# Converting an integer to a string in NASM

Tags: nasm

The question consists of an assembly program that takes an input from a C program and divides it by a number, and returns the remainder to the C program to be printed as a string.

Here is my code for both:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i;
char *str;
str = malloc(1<<9);

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf ("%d", &i);
printf("Number: %i\n", i);
str=int2string(i);
printf("Number as string is: %s\n", str);

return 0;

}
```

ASM =

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data

segment .bss

buffer resd 4   

segment .text
    global int2string
int2string:
    enter   0,0             ; setup routine
    pusha
    mov edx, 0

    mov eax, [ebp+8]        ; eax contains input value of int2string

    mov ebx, 10     ; sets ebx to value of 10
    div ebx         ; eax = eax / ebx

    call print_int      ; prints eax = quotient
    call print_nl       ; next line

    mov eax, edx        ; store edx (remainder) in eax

    call print_int      ; print remainder
    call print_nl       ; next line

    add eax, 48     ; convert result into ASCII character

    popa
    mov dword[buffer], eax  ; move ASCII character (if I replace eax with 48-57
                            ; it prints 0-9 correctly)
    mov eax, buffer     ; move buffer value to eax
    leave                     
    ret
```

My understanding is that the ASCII codes for numbers 0-9 is from the range 48-57, but if I don't put the number explicitly in the buffer move, then the output is either garbage or segmentation fault.

Am I missing something here (eax with a value of 2 + 48, should be ASCII (50) = '2')?

Comment: RESD declares uninitialized storage space, my nasm is rusty but I can't see you null terminating the string you generate.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I originally thought that but, because you're storing a 32-bit register whose value is zero thru nine (chars, so 48 thru 57 integer), it will get stored as val/0/0/0. Automatic null termination, though possibly just an inadverdent side effect :-)

Comment: in the c program description, it states the the 'str' char array is of size 20, so how would i go about initializing storage space to that spec?

Comment: i played around with the code and when i entered 48 as my input, the eax value was '48', hence outputting '0'. To confirm, I found the remainder and stored it to ebx, passed the value to buffer, and then passed it to eax before returning, and it now outputs the correct number.

Comment: thanks for your help, still not sure about the different uses for the e(a-d)x and when to use them appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that either `print_int` or `print_nl` may not preserve the value of `eax` (especially since a common calling convention is to return the result of a function in that register). If your second call to `print_int` prints the right value but the character is wrong, that's a distinct possibility.

An easy test/fix for that is to change:

```
call print_int      ; print remainder
call print_nl       ; next line
```

into:

```
push eax
call print_int      ; print remainder
call print_nl       ; next line
pop eax
```

Other than that, it *looks* okay. All I can suggest is to single step through the code to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: turned out that the eax wasn't storing the value (at least i think?) but i changed the storing location to ebx, then moved to buffer then to eax, seems to be working now, thanks for the input

Comment: @user1074249, `eax` _does_ store the result of the `div` and `edx` the reaminder: (atomic `eax <- edx:eax / <operand>, edx <- edx:eax % <operand>`) so, if it's not what you expect, it probably is the function calls corrupting `eax`.

Comment: i'm having another problem, trying to do the division calculation twice: (14 div 10 = quotient 1, remainder 4 => 1 div 10 = quotient 0, remainder 1) but when i recalculate div ebx, i get something completely off (in the millions)

Comment: @user1074249, I still think it's a good idea to single step to find the actual problem rather than just trying different registers until it works :-) The symptoms of your latest problem match those of your original - `eax` is likely being changed in one of the function calls.

Comment: thank you, i overlooked the same thing again, it works fine now

Comment: @user1074249: feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer if it was truly helpful :-) Is it _indeed_ the fact that `eax` is being changed by one of those functions?

Comment: was a mix of eax being changed and not setting the edx back to 0 when doing multiple divisions, so i cannot pinpoint which was causing the problem at first, but ur solution of debugging manually worked to see the change (or lack thereof) in the eax